# Why isn't my Laravel WebSocket event hitting or showing output?

Tags: laravel, events, chat, listener, phpwebsocket

Using WebSocket in laravel Event neither hits nor shows the output.

I want to create an event using WebSocket in the chat app and want the output on the screen, as I made a channel. but When I write in the terminal " event(new App\Events\UserStatusEvent()); " the event neither hits [ ] in the terminal nor shows the output on the events table.

Comment: you haven't posted any code the only thing that i can say now is to watch this video you will find your problem
https://youtu.be/8RL584c7EsI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.